# Split texts into sentences fast (Java)

Tags: java, performance, nlp, opennlp, sentence

I have a set of article descriptions where I have to split the texts into sentences. The first implementation uses the opennlp tool sentdetect which works very well, but is too slow for my purpose. 
Is there anything similar to this which performs faster and has an outcome of a similar or slightly worse quality?

Note: I'm working with (a huge amount of) short redactional german texts.

Comment: How accurate does it need to be? How well written is the text? book/journal quality - youtube comments quality? Is it feasilble to call external non-java programs?

Comment: Its short redactional texts describing for example clothes. It would be best if it could be done using java, but if there's a good non-java program which handles the texts fast and accurate I would definitely try it. It seems like accuracy and performance work against each other here so I would prioritize the overall performance in this case.

Comment: If the text is reasonably high quality and accracy is not the main priority then regexps are probably the way to go, particularly if you use a regex implementation that compiles regexes to DFAs under the covers. If you want something more sophisticated and OpenNLP is not cutting you will probably need to go outside Java.

Comment: Do you want to write sentences in file / keep it in memory ( which i dont think you are excepting since it is large). Does your text contains any EOL characters ? or just plain text

Comment: The texts are in a database. The main goal is to evaluate the text quality and throw away parts which don't have a lot of meaningful content (e.g. a lot of stopwords and adjectives) and such reduce the texts to the main content (maybe we should do that with our politicians speeches sometimes ;-) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it helps to mention you're working with German :)

A regex-based sentence detector with list of abbreviations can be found in [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/). It uses the three files located [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/). The regular expressions are pretty simple:

```
//more than 2 new lines
(?:[\u00A0\u2007\u202F\p{javaWhitespace}&&[^\n\r]])*(\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r)(?:(?:[\u00A0\u2007\u202F\p{javaWhitespace}&&[^\n\r]])*\1)+

//between 1 and 3 full stops
\.{1,3}"?

//up to 4 ! or ? in sequence
(!|\?){1,4}"?
```

The code that uses these 3 files can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/src/main/gate/creole/splitter/RegexSentenceSplitter.java).

I would enhance the regular expressions with what which could be found on the web, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620514/split-text-file-at-sentence-boundary).

Then I would think of all the German translations of the words in the GATE list. If that's not enough, I would go through a few of these abbreviation lists: [1](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/meyers/abkuerzungen.html), [2](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Abk%C3%BCrzungen/Gebr%C3%A4uchliche_Abk%C3%BCrzungen), and create the list on my own.

EDIT:

If performance is so important, I wouldn't use the whole GATE for a sentence splitter - it would take time and memory to switch to their documents, create annotations, then parse them back, etc.

I think the best way for you is to get the code from RegexSentenceSplitter class (the [link above](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/src/main/gate/creole/splitter/RegexSentenceSplitter.java)) and adjust it to your context.

I think the code is too long to paste here. You should see the execute() method. In general it finds all matches for internal, external and blocking regular expressions, then iterates and uses only those internal and external, which don't overlap with any of the blocking.

Here are some fragments you should look at/reuse:

- How the files are parsed

  ```
  // for each line
  if(patternString.length() > 0) patternString.append("|");
  patternString.append("(?:" + line + ")");

  //...
  return Pattern.compile(patternString.toString());
  ```
- In the execute method, how the blocking splits are filled:

  ```
  Matcher nonSplitMatcher = nonSplitsPattern.matcher(docText);
  //store all non split locations in a list of pairs
  List<int[]> nonSplits = new LinkedList<int[]>();
  while(nonSplitMatcher.find()){
     nonSplits.add(new int[]{nonSplitMatcher.start(), nonSplitMatcher.end()});
  }
  ```

Also check the **veto** method which "Checks whether a possible match is being vetoed by a non split match. A possible match is vetoed if it any nay overlap with a veto region."

Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited my answer to add some guidelines how to implement your sentence detector. I wouldn't use the whole GATE for that, just reuse parts of their code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `String.split("\\. |\\? |! ");` does it?

Comment: I thought about using regex as it is much faster, but this particular version is a bit too simple. Something that could handle abbreviations would also be nice, as these occur regularly in the texts used.

Comment: May we know your definition of a _sentence_ or a _sentenc ending_? I'm sure here are some regex pros around that might create the pattern before you know it ^_^

Comment: A sentence in my definition is ending with .! or ? followed by a space and starts with a capital letter. I don't know how to include the abbreviations though as there are hundreds. If it helps: I'm working with german texts.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think OpenNLP will be better (performance-wise) than rule-based segmenters like Stanford segmenter or implementing a regular expression to solve the task. Rule based segmenters are bound to miss some exceptions. Like, for example, the German sentence, "Ich wurde am 17. Dezember geboren" (I was born on 17th December) will be mistakenly broken into 2 sentences after 17. by a lot of rule-based segmenters, especially if they are built on English rules and not German. Sentences like these will occur even if your text quality is really great as they constitute grammatically correct German. It is very important therefore to check which language-model the segmenter you want to use, is modelled upon.

PS: Amongst OpenNLP, BreakIterator segmenter and Stanford segmenter, OpenNLP worked best for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth mentioning that the Java standard API library provides locale dependent functionality for [detecting test boundaries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/boundaryintro.html). A [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) can be used to determine sentence boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more solution. Dont know how with performance in compare to your solution but for sure the most comprehensive. You can use ICU4J library and srx files. Library you can download here http://site.icu-project.org/download/52#TOC-ICU4J-Download. Works like a charm its multilingual.

```
package srx;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.okapi.common.ISegmenter;
import net.sf.okapi.common.LocaleId;
import net.sf.okapi.common.Range;
import net.sf.okapi.lib.segmentation.LanguageMap;
import net.sf.okapi.lib.segmentation.Rule;
import net.sf.okapi.lib.segmentation.SRXDocument;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(args.length != 2) return;

    SRXDocument doc = new SRXDocument();

    String srxRulesFilePath = args[0];
    String text = args[1];
    doc.loadRules(srxRulesFilePath);
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Rule>> rules =  doc.getAllLanguageRules();
    ArrayList<LanguageMap> languages = doc.getAllLanguagesMaps();
    ArrayList<Rule> plRules = doc.getLanguageRules(languages.get(0).getRuleName());     
    LocaleId locale = LocaleId.fromString("pl_PL");     
    ISegmenter segmenter = doc.compileLanguageRules(LocaleId.fromString("pl_PL"), null);


    segmenter.computeSegments(text);

    List<Range> ranges = segmenter.getRanges();

    System.out.println(ranges.size());
    for (Range range : ranges) {
        System.out.println(range.start);
        System.out.println(range.end);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I like this solution (as it doesn't require bulky OpenNLP while giving the almost identical results for the purpose of splitting to sentences) but it needs some clarification. Actually, you don't need ICU4J library but do need a couple okapi libs located in http://okapiframework.org in order your imports work (okapi-lib-0.32.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, slf4j-jdk14-1.7.13.jar, that's all). And one can get srx files there, too (download okapi-lib_all-platforms_0.32.zip, they are in 'config' folder).